# How to replace specific numbers by another number in a text file (C++)

Tags: c++, replace, floating-point, text-files

First, I want to mention that I'm completely new to C++, so it's possible that I've overlooked any obvious solutions.

**My task is to replace any non-zero number with 1.**

The file looks like this:

```
Some text    
0;0;0;0;0;0.236223;0;0;0;0;0;0.312757;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.367119;... (multiple lines)
```

and should turn into:

```
Some text
0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1,... (multiple lines)
```

My idea was to start out with a string replacement code. I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  ifstream filein( "input.txt" );
  ofstream fileout( "output.txt" );

  string toreplace = "0";
  string replacewith = "1";

  string text;
  while ( getline( filein, text ) )
  {

    for ( size_t p = text.find( toreplace ); p != string::npos;
      p = text.find( toreplace , p ) )
      text.replace( p, toreplace.length(), replacewith );

    fileout << text << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This gives back:

```
1;1;1;1;1;1.236223;1;1;1;1;1;1.312757;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1.367119,...
```

- which is the opposite of what I want (not entirely). So, I thought it would be easy to declare `toreplace` and `replacewith` as floats and use `!= 0`, which didn't work, especially because I can't define `text` as float because it contains ";". (Do I need to remove this delimiter? I would still need it in the final text file.)
- The other problem in that code is that it replaces every zero, which includes "0.236223" turning into "1.236223". I assume this wouldn't matter when eventually working with floats instead of strings.

**Is this the right approach to the given task, or would it be better to do it a different way? Thanks for any help given.**

**EDIT: There was a ";" at the end of each line, which I didn't want and used the string::pop_back() function to resolve the problem.**

Comment: While I usually don't recommend using regular expressions, this might be a situation where it could work well. See [`std::regex_replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) for information about replacing using the standard C++ [regular expression library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: One root issue here is that floating point values can't be compared for equal.  You can read in the data as numbers, then replace the near zero values with a 1.0 value.  Regular expressions have to be careful for leading zero floating point (0.5) or numbers with a zero, such as 1024.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I will have a look into regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream filein("input.txt");
    ofstream fileout("output.txt");

    string toreplace = "0";
    string replacewith = "1";

    string text, new_text="";
    while (getline(filein, text))
    {
        new_text = "";
        double num;

        while (sscanf_s(text.c_str(), "%lf;", &num))
        {
            if (num)
                new_text += "1;";
            else
                new_text += "0;";

            while (text.length() && text.at(0) != ';')
            {
                text.erase(0,1);
            }

            text.erase(0,1);

            if (text.empty())
                break;
        }

        fileout << new_text << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code worked great. It worked better with the original csv file though, because it deleted the text which was included in the txt file. However, eventually using the csv file was my aim anyway. I just thought using the txt file might be easier to start with.

Comment: The only problem which I noticed is the ";" at the end of each line, which I don't want. I'm looking into this now to find a solution.

Comment: simply use string::pop_back() before writing it into the file: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/pop_back/

Comment: That's a handy function. I probably would've tried replacing the ";\n" by just "\n", but this is more efficient. It seemed to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to simplify your input file the solution can be one-liner.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream filein("./data/input.txt"); // Contains 1. 2.3 0. 3.2
    std::ofstream fileout("./data/output.txt"); // Should contain 1. 1. 0. 1.

    std::replace_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<double>(filein), std::istream_iterator<double>(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(fileout," "),
        [](auto v) {return v != 0.; }, 1.);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you have to stick with the ';' delimiter it can be done with a two-liner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream filein("./data/input.txt"); // Contains 1. 2.3 0. 3.2
    std::ofstream fileout("./data/output.txt"); // Should contain 1. 1. 0. 1.
    std::stringstream replaced;
    std::replace_copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(filein), 
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<char>(replaced), 
        [](auto v) { return v == ';'; }, 
        ' ');

    std::replace_copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<double>(replaced), 
        std::istream_iterator<double>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<double>(fileout,";"),
        [](auto v) {return v != 0.; }, 
        1.);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with this though, as it assumes the values are separated by space only. Which the example in the question is not, where the values are semi-colon separated.

Comment: This code produced an empty file for me, I will have another look at it later. However it seemed to work for the original 2-line csv file, expect that it ignored the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

And, just to be complete. The solution with a regex. The regex gives you the ability to specify more precisely what you want to search:

And the result is also an one-liner (one Statement)

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

const std::string testData{"0;0;0;0 ; 0;0.236223;0;0;0;0;0;0.312757;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.367119"};

// This is, what we would like to match. Any number, int or double
const std::regex re{"([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)"};

int main()
{
    std::transform(
        std::sregex_token_iterator(testData.begin(), testData.end(), re, 1),
        std::sregex_token_iterator(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,";"),
        [](const std::string& s) -> int { double d=stod(s); return d==0.0 ? 0 : 1; }
    );
    return 0;
}
```

If you do not want to have the trailing ';' then you can use.

```
std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout,";"),
```

instead of the std::ostream_iterator.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep this regex solution in mind. I'll just have to edit it to be able to read/output a file.